# CSS inline-block divs not displayed right

Tags: css

can anyone please help me? I have this example of list of links with description. http://jsfiddle.net/FcN57/3/ and I need the decription to start at same line as the first link, but it's allways starting one line below. I thought that `inline-block` divs should be displayed side by side

Comment: You are using `<br>` dont use it.  http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/FcN57/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to keep the `<br />` for some reason (although i don't recommend it like the others here), then the following might work for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/FcN57/12/

I added `floats` and a `clear:both` to put them on the same line.

Comment: But when the dscription is long enough to break, the layout changes http://jsfiddle.net/FcN57/17/

Comment: Ok after removing the second float it works just fine, thanks all of you  http://jsfiddle.net/FcN57/23/

Answer (score 0):

You have page breaks in your code. A `<br>` will break the flow and put any elements after it on a new line, regardless of display type.

Remove them and it works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/FcN57/6/

Answer (score 0):

To display description on same line, remove `<br />` tag. Also you can use `span` instead of `div`. `span` will display text on same line.

http://jsfiddle.net/FcN57/10/

Answer (score 0):

They are being displayed inline unfortunatly you've forced a line break here

```
    <div class="EsdVyberDocOdkaz">
        <a href="9CYjKkqzUU71" >link</a>
        <br> //this is your issue
        (
        <a href="9CYjKkqzUU71" >link</a>
        )
    </div>
```

You can either remove that line break and have everything on one line or move your bracketed link after your description like so:

```
<div class="EsdVyberDoc">
        <div class="EsdVyberDocOdkaz">
            <a href="9CYjKkqzUU71" >link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="EsdDocTitul">
            description description description
            </div>
            <br />
            (
            <a href="9CYjKkqzUU71" >link</a>
            )
 </div>
```

Comment: I have similar idea , but when the description is long enough to be on 2 lines, then the links wil be moved one line down. I simply need to have two divs side bz side. In one are links, each on one line and in second is description. And the whole `<li>` should have heigth of the higher `<div>`